# jQuery Quiz matching of array with correct user selection for scoring

Tags: jquery, arrays

Please help! Beginner with jQuery Quiz and my brain is fried...
Here is the JSFiddle for complete code reference: https://jsfiddle.net/CeeSt/644eqae3/16/

My questions involve matching the correct answer within an array of an array with the dynamically created radio selections to create some sort of scoring. My issue has been being able to access the arrays properly and matching the selections with the correct answer. I have console.log(ged) various combinations using this base function, and nothing is working/retrieving properly, what am I doing wrong?:

HTML -

```
  <div id="trivia">
<h1 class="intro">Quizzacious Bananas</h1>
<p class="questions"></p>
<p class="options"></p>
<input id="startGame" type="button" value=""/>
<!--  <input id="playAgain" type="button" value="Play Again"/> -->
```

JS -

```
    $("div.optionsList").on("click", function() {
if ($("div.optionsList").html() === triviaQuestions[currentQuestion].correctSelection) {
      score++;
      console.log(score);
   }
  });
```

Here's example array:

```
var triviaQuestions = [
{
  question: "Where did bananas originate?",
  selection: [" Southeast Asia ", " The Caribbean ", " The Grocery     Store ", " Morocco " ],
  correctSelection: "Southeast Asia"
},
```

Originally my array was this, as I tried accessing the radio button value, but was told to abandon that as it would be to difficult and complicated to accomplish:

```
var triviaQuestions = [
{
  question: "Where did bananas originate?",
  selection: [" Southeast Asia ", " The Caribbean ", " The Grocery     Store ", " Morocco " ],
  correctSelection: 0
},
```

My radio selections were generated this way:

```
function beginGame() {
$(".intro").fadeIn("slow");
if (currentQuestion < triviaQuestions.length) {
  $("#startGame").val("Next Question")
  $("#questionBox").remove();
  $(".optionsList").remove();
  $("p.questions").append('<p id="questionBox">' + triviaQuestions[currentQuestion].question + '</p>');
  $("p.options").append("<p id='quizBox'>");
  var selections = triviaQuestions[currentQuestion].selection;
  //  console.log(selections);
  for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
    $("#quizBox").append("<label><div class='optionsList'><input class='selectRadio' type='radio' name='" + selections[i] +"'/>" + selections[i] + '<br /></div></label>');
  }
  $("#startGame").prepend("</p>");
```

Any assistance in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool project... I have to say.

Ok, I think I fixed everything a saw not to be working.

**Most of the changes** were in this part.
But have a close look at [my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/2aqd9t4m/)... 
I may forget small changes.
I didn't touched HTML or CSS.

```
$("div.optionsList").on("click",".selectRadio", function() {
    console.log("optionsList click event");
    console.log($(this).attr("name"));
    console.log("currentQuestion: "+currentQuestion);
    console.log( $(this).attr("name").trim() );
    console.log( triviaQuestions[currentQuestion-1].correctSelection );
    if ($(this).attr("name").trim() === triviaQuestions[currentQuestion-1].correctSelection) {
        score++;
        console.log("score: "+score);
     }
});
```

As you can see... I added a couple console logs to see what's going on.

The major problem was that you were comparing the answer of the actual question with the already incremented `currentQuestion`... So with the anwser of the next question to come.

That is why you had a console error on the last question.

I fixed your "Play again" button here:

```
else {
    //$("p.questions").remove();
    //$("p.options").remove();
    $("#questionBox").remove();
    $(".optionsList").remove();
    $("#startGame").before('<h2 class="totalScore"> Final score: ' + score + ' / 4 questions corrrect.</h2>');
    $("#startGame").val("Play Again");
    //$("#startGame").remove();
    //$("#playAgain").show();
    currentQuestion=0;
    score = 0;
}
```

By resetting `score` and `currentQuestion` **AND** not removing `p.questions` and `p.options`.

;)

Comment: wow, you're amazing!!! Thanks!!! Just got a chance to look at it, now diving in to see the changes...awesome. :-)

Comment: Look for `.trim()` and why I used it ;) Also worry about script parts that are [triggered by events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/) Think about timing! ;))

Comment: I saw that, and I fixed the spaces and removed the `.trim`, works fantastic...until I add more stuff and break it (again)! thanks again!